# visual c++:linking graphviz in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, graphviz

i want to link graphviz as a library with vc++. 
how should i do that?
i already give path of lib and include than also it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

graphviz is a C library, not a C++ library. Wrap the `#include` in `extern "C" {...}`:

```
extern "C" { // tell C++ that this is a C library
#include "graphviz.h"
}
```